# Excel text to colum, reverse the outcome

Tags: excel

I have a long list of addresses, the whole address is in a single cell, each 'line' of the address is separated by a comma. I need to be able to extract just the post code. An example of the current data is as follows,

```
Red House, Street, Town, City, YO13 9DY
Blue House, Street, YP8 2FR
Black House, Street, City, L10 1AA
Green House, Street, Street 2, Town, City, PO5T CDE
```

As you can see each address follows the same pattern, using the same comma as divider, however all are different lengths.

Text to columns works to some extent, but due to the layout of each cell, the post code always ends up in a different column.

Is there a way to reverse this output, so similar to Text to Columns, but each deliminator is printed in reverse order?

If I not explained this very well please say and I shall attempt to re-word.

Comment: Are you open to use VBA? Then you can run a macro. Postal code is the part after the last comma, I guess? If it is so then you can get the value of each cell, use Split function with comma as a delimiter, then get the last element of the array that the Split returns. This last element is the postal code.

Comment: Thats correct, the postcode will always be the part after the last comma, if it will be the easiest option to use VBA then I will look down that route and attempt to do as you suggested. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Text to columns you can use this to get only what is after the last comma :

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))+1,LEN(A1)))
```

(Assuming A1 contains the full address like in your example)

Comment: Brilliant thank you, threw the whole thing in an IF statement to remove blank errors and we're winning!

Answer (score 0):

If the postal code is in a different column, you can take the value of the last (non-empty) column with the following code (put in H1 and other columns in B1-G1):

```
=IF(G1<>"";G1;IF(F1<>"";F1;IF(E1<>"";E1;IF(D1<>"";D1;IF(C1<>"";C1;IF(B1<>"";B1;""))))))
```

If your language is different, you might want to change all `;` to `,`.

You can easily expand if the number of columns is larger, or with other constraints,...